# Limit of continuous function of $x$ and $y$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, functions

Let ${ g\left(x,y\right) \in \mathbb{R} }$ be a continuous function, such that ${ \forall x \leq y :  g\left(x,y\right) = f\left(x,y\right)} $.
I want to show that $f$ is continuous.

My question is if I can argue the following, for $(x_0, y_0)$  where $ x \leq y$ ?

${  \lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0, y_0)} f\left(x,y\right) =  \lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0, y_0)} g\left(x,y\right) = g\left(x_0,y_0\right) = f\left(x_0,y_0\right)}$

Comment: The notation $g(x,y)\to \mathbb R$ probably should be $g(x,y)\in\mathbb R$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you restrict $x\leq y$ then yes, the reasoning is sound, since you are taking arbitrary $(x_0,y_0)$.

If $g(x,y)=f(x,y)$ for all $x\leq y$, this implies $f$ and $g$ share the same limit as $(x,y)$ approach $(x_0,y_0)$. These two functions share the same properties for $x\leq y$, hence $f$ is continuous.